# When to Split Data for Time Series Forecasting using Ensemble Empirical Mode Decomposition?

Tags: time-series, model-evaluation, decomposition, train-test-split

I want to forecast a time series data by using Ensemble Empirical Mode Decomposition (EEMD) and LSTM.

However, I'm unsure about when to split the data into training and test sets. Should the data be split before decomposition, or after?

I've come across a few research papers where individual IMF forecasts are being compared with test IMFs. This comparison suggests that they might have performed the train-test split after decomposition, which intrigues me. However, it's not clear to me how these comparisons are made without risking data leakage, as EEMD is a data-driven technique.

And, If decomposition is performed after the split, I could end up with a different number of IMFs for the training and testing sets. This poses a challenge for evaluating the performance of each individual IMF forecast.

What could be the correct way to evaluate the performance of individual IMF forecasts?

Could anyone provide insight or resources on the correct procedure and how to deal with these issues?